# Return value of related object with condition

Tags: django, django-orm

As for example I've got 3 models: User, Event, Participator

```
class Event(..):
    creator = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_creator_set')


class Participator(..):
    status = models.CharField(..)
    event = models.ForeignKey('events.Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participators_set')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participations_set')
```

I want to get all user's and also get information about relation with specific event. If user is even't participator -> return status from Participator models, else -> null
    Here is my queries:

```
 e = Event.objects.first()
 users = User.objects.annotate(is_participationg=Case(When(id__in=e.participators_set.values_list('user__id', flat=True), then=Value(True)), default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField()))
```

So I can know whether user is participating in specific event. How can I get user's participating status in `then` and None in `default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated, you *know* the `id` of the event, so you can filter like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, F, Max, Value, When

User.objects.annotate(
    participation_status=Max(Case(
        When(participations_set__event=e, then=F('participations_set__status')),
        default=Value(None),
        output_field=CharField()
    ))
)
```

This then results in the query:

```
SELECT user.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN participator.event_id = 123
           THEN participator.status
           ELSE NULL END
       ) AS participation_status
FROM user
LEFT OUTER JOIN participator ON (user.id = participator.user_id)
GROUP BY user.id
```

(with `123` in reality the primary key of `e`).

In case the `User` participated in the event in multiple ways, the lexicographical maximum status will be used.